# Mustache JavaScript: Looping Through Arrays of Objects Output

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have this template code:

```
{{#priceList}}
  {{#last}}
    <strong>{{currency}}</strong>
  {{/last}}
  {{^last}}
    <del>{{currency}}</del>
  {{/last}}
{{/finalPriceList}}
```

and I'm trying to go through this data:

```
priceList: [
  { price: 50, currency: '$50.00', last: false },
  { price: 25, currency: '$25.00', last: true }
]
```

All I want to do is output:

```
<del>$50.00</del> <strong>$25.00</strong>
```

Am I approaching this right? I've tried `last` as `undefined` instead of `false` as well.

My code outputs

```
<del>$50.00</del> {{/last}} <strong>$25.00</strong> <del>$25.00</strong> {{/last}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template was incorrect - had `{{/finalPriceList}}`, should have been `{{/priceList}}`, i.e.:

```
{{#priceList}}
  {{#last}}
    <strong>{{currency}}</strong>
  {{/last}}
  {{^last}}
    <del>{{currency}}</del>
  {{/last}}
{{/priceList}}
```

See a working example here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/UyNys/

Comment: Oddly enough I had that right in the code and it was still giving me the error. I switched the {{^}} and {{#}} position and it outputs fine. It must be something sooner in my template that causes it? Either way. Thank you very much! It's good to know I was actually doing it right.

Comment: Hm, strange... How are you loading the file - check the jsFiddle example I gave and see if there's anything different in your code. If you are building it as a string, you need `\` as the last character to have it continue lines. You should probably use Firebug or something like that to see if you get any error messages - that would help greatly pinpointing the issue.

Comment: I feel like an absolute crazy person but it's working the other way now as well. I am using jQuery to get the template code, just `Mustache.to_html( $('.product.template').html(), product );` When it wasn't working I wasn't getting any error messages. Feel free to ignore me now. Thank you again. =)

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted out!